# How do I make a form submit with a LinkButton?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, form-submit, linkbutton

My login usercontrol has two text boxes and a linkbutton.

```
<asp:TextBox id="tbUserName" runat="server" size="10" />
<asp:TextBox id="tbPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" size="10" />

<asp:LinkButton Text="login" CssClass="submit"  runat="server" ID="lbLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_OnClick" />
```

I would like to call the "btnLogin_OnClick function when someone pushes enter on tbUsername or tbPassword.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a neat trick:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogon" runat="server" DefaultButton="lbLogin" Width="100%" >
        <asp:TextBox id="tbUserName" runat="server" size="10" />
        <asp:TextBox id="tbPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" size="10" />
        <asp:LinkButton Text="login" CssClass="submit"  runat="server" ID="lbLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_OnClick" />
</asp:Panel>
```

By wrapping the textboxes in a panel and setting the `DefaultButton` of the Panel to your `LinkButton`, any Enter in the text box inside the panel will cause the `LinkButton` Click to happen.

Comment: Thanks!  This works in IE and Firefox but not chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe due to this? http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/

Comment: Brilliant, I had to follow the instructions in the link above for it to work in safari.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

// Code-behind

```
protected void btnLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // process your form
    }
}
```

Comment: That function doesn't get called when someone pushes enter on tbUserName or tbPassword.  It only get's called on click.

Comment: Sorry Nate, I misread the question. Either Mrchief's method should work.