# ASP.NET Prevent Form Validation with HTML 5 Submit Button

Tags: asp.net, html, button, webforms, submit

I'm trying to use the HTML 5 button element to submit an ASP.NET form. I also want it to not trigger validation when clicked. This will submit the form, but will still cause validation to trigger:

```
<button runat="server"
CausesValidation="false"
type="submit"
name="myButton"
id="myButton">Press Here</button>
```

I'm specifically trying to not use HTML input or ASP:Button elements. They both will work, but don't allow HTML (images etc..) within the button text.

An example validation element on my page:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
ValidationGroup="myValGroup"
ControlToValidate="phone"
ID="phoneRequiredVal"
runat="server"
ErrorMessage="Phone is required."
Display="Dynamic"
CssClass="defaultErrorText"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you implement editors validation?

Comment: I added how I implemented my validators. Not sure if you were asking for something else.

Comment: I've checked your code, it does not cause form validation on the client side. The form is submitted correctly. However, I see the Event Validation error. Did you mean the Event validation issue?

Comment: For me, when I click the button, the page reloads (postback) and the validators all have their error messages displayed. I want the validators to ignore this button when it is clicked. When I change the <button> to an <input> it works as expected, however I'm trying to put HTML inside the button text and I can't do that with an input's value attribute.

Comment: My best guess at this point is that ASP.NET simply doesn't support the HTML 5 button element at all. The only reason the form gets submitted for me is that is it actually HTML/browser that does the form submission and posting of variables, and ASP just does work with them on the back end. Also why causesvalidation="false" isn't doing anything. If anyone can confirm that would be great. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the LinkButton control. Looks like this is what I needed to submit the form, have HTML within the tags, and be able to halt validation:

```
<asp:LinkButton
runat="server"
CausesValidation="false"
CssClass="button fullWidth">Press Here</asp:LinkButton>
```

Found here:
[How do I make a form submit with a LinkButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217265/how-do-i-make-a-form-submit-with-a-linkbutton)

Answer (score 0):

Although you use an HTML tag (`<button>`) as a server-side control (`<button runat="server" ...>`), the ASP.NET server does not expect this component as a postback or callback sender. As a result, the Event Validation error occurs on the server side during form submit.

To resolve this issue, register the button as a postback sender using [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397(v=vs.110).aspx)  method:

`public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("myButton");
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}`

Comment: I tried adding this code to the class for my page, however it didn't seem to have any effect on my issue.